# Angular 1.5 component calling ng-change infinitily

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change, angular-components

I have a component, lets say comx,

```
angular.component('comx', {
    templateUrl: 'someUrl',
    bindings: {
       model: '=',
       onChng: '='
    } 
}
```

and its html is

```
<input ng-model="vm.model" ng-change="vm.onChng">
```

and I'm adding this component in other template like

```
<comx model="vm.data" on-chng="vm.test(vm.data)">

vm.test = function (val) {
   console.log(val);  // val is printing infinitly
}
```

The above function's console is keep on printing

Comment: why not using `&` for expression? it should be `onChng: '&'` instead

Comment: tried that already, but weirdly its giving previous data of vm.data not the new one.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in plunker/fiddle?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle/plunker or provide some more code.

Answer (score 2):

> @pankj: why not using `&` for expression?
>
> @amir: tried that already, but weirdly its giving previous data of `vm.data` not the new one.

That happens because two-way `=` binding uses a watcher to transfer the data from isolate scope to parent scope. That happens on the dirty-checking cycle after the ng-change operation.

To provide the isolate scope value immediately, expose it as a local variable:

```
angular.component('comx', {
    template: '<input ng-model="$ctrl.model" '+
              '       ng-change="$ctrl.onChng({$model: $ctrl.model})">',
    bindings: {
       model: '=',
       onChng: '&'
    } 
});
```

Usage:

```
<comx model="vm.data" on-chng="vm.test($model)">
</comx>
```

```
vm.test = function (val) {
   console.log(val);
};
```

By exposing the model as a local variable, it is available immediately for the function in the parent scope.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajwjw9db/).

Comment: Whats wrong here is `ng-change="$ctrl.onChng({$model: $ctrl.model})` in the component's template. This will passes value correctly, but what I want is a customizable function, the parameters of the function should be given in the parent controller where the component is called. On change just trigger that function.